# How do you meet your daily protein goals?

Tags: protein, whey

I'm pretty new to lifting and I've learnt that you need **ATLEAST** 1gm/lb of bodyweight protein each day. When you are cutting, your protein requirements should be ~ 1.5-1.8gm/lb of your body weight (source : Bigger Leaner Stronger).

I have been an **eggetarian** for my entire life and I have never used any supplements whatsoever (Whey protein for example). I'm finding it almost impossible to even get ~ 100gms of protein a day!

Recently I started eating **9** boiled eggs a day(7 whites, 2 whole) but my parents were getting paranoid that it could hurt my liver or something, so I cut down to 4. Then I tried **frozen chicken** for the first time, and honestly I was about to vomit. I tried it again and this time it was edible (I did NOT like it at all, though).
So how do you do it guys!? Eating 160-190gms of protein a day looks IMPOSSIBLE to me. Unrealistic. How do you even manage to do it? Is it even possible to do it without the meat?

Comment: I'd just increase the number of eggs you eat. They're perfectly safe. https://www.jprasurg.com/article/0007-1226(75)90127-7/pdf

Comment: Legumes (Beans etc.) are good sources of protein.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a preface, it is important to point out that there is *no evidence* to support the claims made by your source. In fact, a large body of scientific literature suggests that the maximum amount of protein we can utilise is about 2.0 g/kg/day (0.9 g/lb/d), with approximately 1.5-1.6 g/kg/d (~0.7 g/lb/d) being optimum for most strength, power, and endurance athletes. This matter is discussed in greater length [here](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/42065/more-protein-more-potential-for-muscle-growth/42083#42083).

Most people who follow such high protein diets *do* indeed use supplementation, since it is by far the easiest way to meet their protein goals. However, it is entirely possible to attain that same protein through whole- rather than refined foods. Being ovo-vegetarian (or ‘eggetarian’) presents further challenges, too, but those challenges are not insurmountable. The principle problem is that plant protein is always accompanied by significant quantities of starch, fibre, and water, and that means that it is necessary to eat a larger volume of food. This can be a problem for those who do not have a large appetite. Furthermore, plants tend to have significantly lower proportions of one or more [essential amino acids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_amino_acid), and we must therefore eat a broad variety of different classes of plant, such that the amino acids that are scarce in one are abundant in the other, and *vice versa*. This is normally not a problem for anyone who eats a diversity of foods, but again, it can present a challenge to fussy eaters.

The key, therefore, is to identify which plant-based foods have higher protein contents, and to eat a broad variety of those foods. It is optimum to combine foods that complement each other in a single meal—a practice known as [protein complementation](https://nutrition.org/protein-complementation/)—but not necessary. Provided that our overall consumption includes appreciable amounts of each essential amino acid, the benefits are similar. Of course, as an ovo-vegetarian, plant-based meals may be combined with eggs, or supplemented with [ovalbumin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ovalbumin#:~:text=Ovalbumin%20(abbreviated%20OVA)%20is%20the,not%20a%20serine%20protease%20inhibitor.).

From the source above, the classes of food that should be combined are as follows:

```
Class          Scarce amino acids     Complement

Legumes        Methionine             Grains, nuts/seeds
Grains         Lysine, threonine      Legumes
Nuts/seeds     Lysine                 Legumes
Vegetables     Methionine             Grains, nuts/seeds
Corn/maize     Tryptophan, lysine     Legumes
```

Some plant foods such as soy, quinoa, and amaranth contain appreciable quantities of *all* of the essential amino acids, and are therefore described as having higher *protein quality*. However, it is important to point out that provided the amino acids are present in combination, the quality of plant protein is identical to that of meat.

If a broad variety of protein-rich plant-based foods are consumed, total protein consumption can be calculated in exactly the same manner as normal, summing the individual protein contents of each component food.

Some common protein-dense plant-based foods are listed below.

```
Food                    Approximate protein/100 g

Peanuts, raw            25.8 g
Wheat germ              23.1 g
Tofu, firm              15.8
Bread, multigrain       13.4 g
Shredded wheat          11.4 g
Lentils, brown          9.0 g
Chickpeas               8.9 g
Quinoa                  4.4 g
Amaranth                3.8 g
Sweet corn              3.3 g
Rice, white long-grain  2.7 g
Broccoli                2.4 g
```

These data are sourced from [SELFNutritionData](https://nutritiondata.self.com/). It should be noted that data vary greatly between different sources, reflecting varieties, seasonal variation, and different testing protocol.

Eating a variety of different foods, spacing your meals, and if necessary complementing your plant sources with eggs and/or ovalbumin, high-quality protein intake of above 100 grams is entirely achievable. But as stated at the beginning of this post, it is unnecessary for all but the most extreme (endurance) athletes.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Great answer! I just discovered that 100gm of soyabean chunks contain 52gm Protein!

Answer (score 0):

You're fine with 1 gram per pound. Also I do 1 gram per pound of lean mass, because naturally if you're overweight you don't need to use your weight as a measurement. Here is what I eat:

Fage yogurt(20 grams of protein, the 0% fat one has 18)

Packaged or canned salmon(30 grams)

Packaged or canned tuna(30 grams)

Chicken(40)

Turkey(40)

Skim milk(fairlife brand has 13 grams of protein and half the carbs for just 8 ounces, which is the amount you add to a bowl of cereal or a small cup. Couple times a day)

Casein protein(25 grams a serving, take once before bed, and once during day on non training days)

Cheese(if not cutting has 6 grams)

Lentils, black beans, chickpeas(protein and good source of carbs)

Cod

Veggie burgers(my favorite, 16 grams, and very quick to microwave and make, also cheap)

Eggs(keep it to max 3 whole a day, egg whites are fine).

Steak(cheap steak is fine couple times a week, steak and eggs are my fave breakfast)

Deli meat(reduced fat)

Power bowls or fit kitchen frozen dinners

Supplement using casein. Unless you're drinking it post workout then drink whey protein. Casein digests very slowly so it feeds protein to your muscles 4 to 6 hours as opposed to whey.